# ruby - what is the difference between uniq! and uniq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.uniq!  # nil
a.uniq  # [1,2,3]
```

Why a.uniq! is not [1,2,3] ?

Let me know the reason. Thank you!

Comment: [http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use Stack Overflow as a replacement for reading the documentation and doing your research. Please read "[ask]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 8, accepted):

most of the methods ending with bang (!) change the variable, while those without it just return the altered variable.

So, if you have something like this:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

`a.uniq` will return `[1, 2, 3]`, but wont alter `a`, while `a!` will alter `a` to be equal to `[1, 2, 3]`

```
[1] pry(main)> a = [1,1,2,3]
=> [1, 1, 2, 3]
[2] pry(main)> a.uniq
=> [1, 2, 3]
[3] pry(main)> a
=> [1, 1, 2, 3]
[4] pry(main)> a.uniq!
=> [1, 2, 3]
[5] pry(main)> a
=> [1, 2, 3]
[6] pry(main)> a.uniq!
=> nil
[7] pry(main)> a
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It is worth noting that, while the bang is used to denote "dangerous" methods in ruby as @bosskovic said, you can't always safely assume this is the case. For instance, a number of active record methods (such as .save! and .create!) use the bang to denote that they will raise an exception if they fail instead of returning false. It's safest to look them up on a method-by-method basis, as there is no enforcing that either of these conventions are followed.

Comment: This answer does not explain the `nil`.

Answer (score 11):

You need to read the [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/) documentation.

The [`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-uniq) method returns a new array by removing duplicate values in self. If no duplicates are found, the same array value is returned.

```
a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
a.uniq  # => ["a", "b", "c"]

b = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
b.uniq  # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

The [`uniq!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) method removes duplicate elements from self and returns `nil` if no changes are made (that is, no duplicates are found).

```
a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
a.uniq!   # => ["a", "b", "c"]

b = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
b.uniq!   # => nil
```

Comment: Is not the first one "uniq"?

Comment: this answer explains the `nil`. +1.